Read from multiple files and merge them in a stream by condition
I have several csv files with next structure
{"unixTimestampMs":1609531200000,"timezoneId":"Europe/Moscow","payload":...}
I need to read all of them in a zstream by time condition. (ex. take 10 records from first file, then 5 records from second file, 15 records from third file and so on by round robin system and ordered by time)
Previously I had single file and it was like that:
def fileStream: Stream[Throwable, Result] =
    for {
      res <-
        fileSource(appConf.sourceFilePath)
          .mapZIO(transactionService.mkMsgFromString)
          .collectSome
          .groupAdjacentBy(_.unixTimestampMs)
          .map(evenlyDistributeMessages)
          .flatMap(ZStream.fromChunk(_))
          .mapZIO(sleepIfRequired)
          .mapZIOPar(proxyConf.maxConnections, proxyConf.maxConnections)(emitMessage(_, uriToSendMessages))
    } yield res

where
def fileSource(file: String): Stream[Throwable, String] =
    ZStream
      .acquireReleaseWith(transactionsFileService.getFileAsSource(file))(releaseFile)
      .flatMap(f => ZStream.fromIterator(f.getLines().drop(1), 256))

so fileSource gives me my expected stream.
How to rewrite it for multiple files case and merge in a zstream ordered by time?

Sounds like ZStream#interleaveWith might be the operation you need to use. It merge two streams deterministically

Just curious, how many files are we taliking about here? Also, I feel the requirements are not clear. How many files are you getting concurrently, and do these files have date/time values clustered around the current date/time? What if an hour later you get some files that have dates around the same time as the files from an hour ago. The easiest thing to do is to shove the records in a (no)sql table  and let sql do the sorting.

interleaveWith doesn't fit because it does merge without condition

It could be from two and more files. FIles could be from different days but it doesn't matter because I will drop the date and leave time only

Finally I found solution:
def fileStream: Stream[Throwable, Result] =
    for {
      res <- appConf.sourceFileList
          .map(fileSource)
          .map(_.mapZIO(transactionService.mkMsgFromString))
          .map(_.collectSome)
          .reduce(_ mergeSorted _)
          .groupAdjacentBy(_.unixTimestampMs)
          .map(evenlyDistributeMessages)
          .flatMap(ZStream.fromChunk(_))
          .mapZIO(sleepIfRequired)
          .mapZIOPar(proxyConf.maxConnections, proxyConf.maxConnections)(emitMessage(_, uriToSendMessages))
    } yield res

appConf.sourceFileList is a list if file names.
And also to use mergeSorted I implemented Ordering[T].

What does sleepIfRequired do in this context?
